# Cut a hole using another shapelayer

Tags: polygon, editing, holes, qgis-3

I have an problem with cut an hole in a shapefile with another shapefile in QGIS version 3.12, I have previously used 2.18 for this. But when i tried that function in 3.12 it happens absolutly nothing.

Function: `"cut with selected polygon"`

[image: example]

Comment: Which toolbar is this?

Comment: Hi it's Digitizing tools

Comment: And this is built-in? I've never seen the symbols before.

Comment: Are the two polygons on the same layer? With two polygons on the same layer, it works here with me

Comment: if they are different layers then look at `difference` in the processing toolbox

Comment: Erik- no that's a plugin downloaded from qgis website. Great tool.

Comment: Erik- no that's a plugin downloaded from qgis website. And that is a great tool when it's working. Babel- no I'm using two diffrent shapefiles when I do the cutting. Ian- yeah that's works, the problem with that is that i must to a new file for every cutting

Comment: @user163650 many plugins which worked for 2.X stopped working for 3.X, probably this one too.

Comment: It is most likely so. Too bad it's a very good plugin otherwise. I guess I'll have to keep using 2.18 to cut shapefiles Thanks all för your time